# Coding myself into a corner

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop

We've got a set of classes which derive from a common set of interfaces such that

```
IFoo-> BasicFoo, ReverseFoo, ForwardFoo
IBar -> UpBar, DownBar, SidewaysBar
IYelp -> Yip, Yap, Yup
```

wherein the constructor for the Foo's looks like `Foo(IBar, IYelp)`  These items are used throughout the project.

There exists another class which has a method whose signature is `public double CalcSomething(IFoo, IAnotherClass)` that is applied at some point to each and every Foo.  We've had a request come down from above that one particular object composition, let's say a `BasicFoo(UpBar,Yip)`, use a different algorithm other than the one found in `CalcSomething`.

My first instinct was to say let's change the IFoo interface so we can move the logic down to the Foo class level, change the constructor to be `Foo(IBar, IYelp, IStrategy)` and then have the Foo objects encapsulate this logic.  Unfortunately we've also been told the design of the architecture stipulates that there be no dependencies between `IFoo`, it's implementations and `IAnotherClass`.  They're adamant about this.

Ok, sure, then I thought I might use a visitor pattern but... how?  The whole point of making the composition was so that no other class could see the implementation details.  Reflection to look inside the objects, totally breaking encapsulation?  Oh hell no.

So I've come here because I'm at a loss.  Does anyone have any suggestions how we could treat a special case of one of the compositions without modifying the composition or breaking encapsulation?  There has got to be a simple solution I'm over-looking.

Edit:

Removed offending beginning.
Changed "handled specially" into a more descriptive meaning.

Comment: When you have a wart in the spec, you're likely to have a wart in the implementation.  I don't see a way to do this very cleanly.

Comment: The primary point I don't understand -- how does encapsulating the special logic in the class that inherits `IFoo` create a dependency on `IAnotherClass`?

Comment: Well, delfuego, if I moved it to Foo the method would have to have the signature IFoo::CalcSomething(IAnotherClass).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CalculationFactory` that chooses an appropriate algorithm based on the type of `IFoo` you provide would solve the problem (at the cost of a conditional):

```
interface ICalcSomethingStrategy {
    public double CalcSomething(IFoo, IAnotherClass);
}

CalcSomethingStrategyFactory {
    ICalcSomethingStrategy CreateCalcSomethingStrategy(IFoo foo) {
        // I'm not sure whether this is the idiomatic java way to check types D:
        if (foo.Bar instanceof UpBar && foo instanceof Yip) {
            return new UnusualCalcSomethingStrategy();
        } else {
            return new StandardCalcSomethingStrategy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We were just discussing if this could accomplish what we're trying to do.  We don't see any other way around using reflection to get to the bottom of how to split things up.

Comment: Although the coupling is tighter, you might look at this in terms of giving clients a Context from which to call `calcSomething()`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Java

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of KISS I would add a method isSpecial() to IFoo, and use that to decide which algorithm to use in CalcSomething().

This assumes that this is the only special case.

Comment: +1 agreed, the factory approach I suggested is probably heavier than it needs to be if this is a one-time only affair.

Comment: +1 indeed.  Simple, tidy, and sufficient.  If your "only special case" assumption is violated, isSpecial() could be refactored to return a "calculation algorithm to apply" value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for calcSomething to avoid having the knowledge needed to do the "special" behavior, but other than that, you can maintain most of your encapsulation this way.

Create a marker interface IQualifyForSpecialTreatment which extends IFoo.  Extend BasicFoo to SpecialBasicFoo, and have it implement IQualifyForSpecialTreatment.

```
    interface IQualifyForSpecialTreatment extends IFoo {
    }
    class SpecialBasicFoo extends BasicFoo implements IQualifyForSpecialTreatment {
        ...
    }
```

You can then add another flavor of calcSomething:

```
    calcSomething (IQualifyForSpecialTreatment foo, IAnotherClass whatever) {
        ... perform "special" variant of calculation
    }
    calcSomething (IFoo foo, IAnotherClass whatever) {
        ... perform "normal" variant of calculation
    }
```